Subversion SWIG python3 bindings don't work om Alpine 3.17 or newer
Here is my situation:
FROM alpine:3.20 
RUN apk --no-cache add --update --virtual .builddeps build-base python3-dev && \ 
    apk add py3-subversion

When I execute the following line
python3 -c "import libsvn.core" 

I get
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.12/libsvn/core.py", line 27, in <module>
  from . import _core
ImportError: Error relocating /usr/lib/python3.12/libsvn/_core.so: SWIG_Python_str_AsChar: symbol not found

The same code runs in Alpine 3.16 just fine.

I don't think the problem is Alpine. If the function is missing, it is missing. Try to see if the problem is not the lazy binding. Maybe 3.17 tries to resolve all symbols at startup.

3.17. 3.18, 3.19. 3.20  do not work. libsvn from 3.16 on 3.17 do not work.  Recompile from source do not work.

Try those that work with export LD_BIND_NOW=1

Same results here.
